# Cannot load images on my 360 degree slider

Tags: jquery, css

I am new at java script so I literally copy and paste the code and I think it's not loading the images properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" 
href="../../CONTENT/Images/Logo/ICO.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles/threesixty.css">
<title>pappu-lighting</title>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="threesixty" id="mythreesixty">
    <div class="spinner">
        <span>0%</span>
    </div>
   <ol class="threesixty_images"></ol>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="src/threesixty.js"></script>    
<script>
window.onload = init;

var product;
function init(){

my360 = $('#mythreesixty').ThreeSixty({
    totalFrames: 72, // Total no. of image you have for 360 slider
    endFrame: 72, // end frame for the auto spin animation
    currentFrame: 1, // This the start frame for auto spin
    imgList: '.threesixty_images', // selector for image list
    progress: '.spinner', // selector to show the loading progress
    imagePath:'assets/product1', // path of the image assets
    filePrefix: 'ipod-', // file prefix if any
    ext: '.jpg', // extention for the assets
    height: 265,
    width: 400,
    navigation: true,
    disableSpin: true // Default false
    });

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So my Images source is in the same folder in directory: /assets/product1/

I don't really know whats wrong, but all the plugins and CSS files áre loaded properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of Three Sixty Image slider

```
<div class="threesixty product1">
    <div class="spinner">
        <span>0%</span>
    </div>
    <ol class="threesixty_images"></ol>
</div>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = init;

    var product;
    function init(){

        product1 = $('.product1').ThreeSixty({
            totalFrames: 72, // Total no. of image you have for 360 slider
            endFrame: 72, // end frame for the auto spin animation
            currentFrame: 1, // This the start frame for auto spin
            imgList: '.threesixty_images', // selector for image list
            progress: '.spinner', // selector to show the loading progress
            imagePath:'assets/product1/', // path of the image assets
            filePrefix: 'ipod-', // file prefix if any
            ext: '.jpg', // extention for the assets
            height: 265,
            width: 400,
            navigation: true,
            disableSpin: true // Default false
        });

    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified your directory correctly
add a `'/'` after `product1` so that the images inside could be read properly

```
 imagePath:'assets/product1/', // path of the image assets
```

Comment: Nothing changed... My images are named 1.jpg/2.jpg/3.jpg etc. Do I need to change their name? this filePrefix? Do they need to be renamed to:   
ipod-1.jpg/ipod-2.jpg...

Comment: No need to rename

Comment: what about imagePath:'/assets/product1/',

Comment: I changed the name of the photos to ipod-1/ipod-2 etc and it worked